# How to refresh the content of a UIView filled with photos

Tags: uiview, xcode4, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

i have a modal view that is called from a table view. Whenever i call the modal view, i set a small view, inside the modal view, with some scrollable pictures inside it. The problem is that when i go back to the table view and select another row of the table, the old images are supposed to disappear and the new ones appear instead, but that is not happening. Seems like when i first load the modal view, it fills with the initial 2 pics and when i load it again it keeps adding the new pictures with the old ones..

Here is the code:

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages {
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];
//NSMutableArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(([self.nomeFotos count] * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

and:

```
- (void)setScrollingImages {
//self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundCol];

// 1. setup the scrollview for multiple images and add it to the view controller
//
// note: the following can be done in Interface Builder, but we show this in code for clarity
[scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;        // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;

// pagingEnabled property default is NO, if set the scroller will stop or snap at each photo
// if you want free-flowing scroll, don't set this property.
scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;

// load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= [self.nomeFotos count]; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[self.nomeFotos objectAtIndex:(i-1)]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    NSLog(@"%@", imageName);
    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
}

[self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figured what i wanted, a solution is to remove all the current subviews and then add the new views.. the code is as follow:

```
for (UIView* subView in [self.view.subviews]) {
    [subView removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```

I put this code in my view will appear and everytime the view appears, it clears its subviews and the i call the method to add the new subviews (pictures).

Thanks